# SSRS stacked two series column chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I want to create a chart which should display this data structure:

[image]

The chart should be something like that:

[image]

On x - Sum of Sum_POS_PREIS_NETTO seperated by KLASSIFIKATION

On y - Group by POS_SACHKONTO and MONTH

Is there any way to do that? I'm working on Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder.
Thank you

Comment: The default options are either stacked columns *or* side-by-side columns.  I think this is only possible with some tricks to get the columns to show properly.  How much control do you have over the Datasets that feed this report, as this chart will need its own?

Comment: I can customize the dataset by my own. But dont know which changes have to be applied there

Comment: How many different combinations of `Klassifikation` and `POS_Sachkonto` are there?  If there are a lot I think this may be impossible, but also that this type of chart would be a bad way to display this data anyway.  It would be concise, but terrible for actually using to compare the data over time.